# Scraping table from myneta using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from http://myneta.info/uttarpradesh2017/index.php?action=summary&subAction=candidates_analyzed&sort=candidate#summary to my R studio.

**Here's the code**

```
url<-'http://myneta.info/uttarpradesh2017/index.php?action=summary&subAction=candidates_analyzed&sort=candidate#summary'
webpage<-read_html(url)
candidate_info<- html_nodes(webpage,xpath='//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table')
candidate_info<- html_table(candidate_info)
head(candidate_info)
```

But getting no output, suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what led you to that XPath?

Comment: Inspecting the page in chrome and copying the xpath of the HTML tag where the table get highlighted by hovering over the Tag.

Comment: I provided a different XPath in the answer. One big issue with the copy method (and for Selector Gadget users out there) is that _rendered_ HTML may be quite different than _source_ HTML and `rvest` (`xml2`, really) only deals with _source_ HTML.

Comment: This was very helpful and solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome. Web scraping can be super frustrating. I'm just glad the table columns weren't uneven. Those are a bear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site has some very broken HTML. But, it's workable.

I find it better to target nodes in a slightly less fragile way. The XPath below finds it by content of the table.

`html_table()` croaks (or took forever and I didn't want to wait) so I ended up building the table "manually".

```
library(rvest)

# helper to clean column names
mcga <- function(x) { make.unique(gsub("(^_|_$)", "", gsub("_+", "_",  gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+", "_", tolower(x)))), sep = "_") }

pg <- read_html("http://myneta.info/uttarpradesh2017/index.php?action=summary&subAction=candidates_analyzed&sort=candidate#summary")

# target the table
tab <- html_node(pg, xpath=".//table[contains(thead, 'Liabilities')]")

# get the rows so we can target columns
rows <- html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//tr[td[not(@colspan)]]")

# make a data frame
do.call(
  cbind.data.frame,
  c(lapply(1:8, function(i) {
    html_text(html_nodes(rows, xpath=sprintf(".//td[%s]", i)), trim=TRUE)
  }), list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
) -> xdf

# make nicer names
xdf <- setNames(xdf, mcga(html_text(html_nodes(tab, "th")))) # get the header to get column names

str(xdf)
## 'data.frame': 4823 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ sno          : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
##  $ candidate    : chr  "A Hasiv" "A Wahid" "Aan Shikhar Shrivastava" "Aaptab Urf Aftab" ...
##  $ constituency : chr  "ARYA NAGAR" "GAINSARI" "GOSHAINGANJ" "MUBARAKPUR" ...
##  $ party        : chr  "BSP" "IND" "Satya Shikhar Party" "Islam Party Hind" ...
##  $ criminal_case: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
##  $ education    : chr  "12th Pass" "10th Pass" "Graduate" "Illiterate" ...
##  $ total_assets : chr  "Rs 3,94,24,827 ~ 3 Crore+" "Rs 75,106 ~ 75 Thou+" "Rs 41,000 ~ 41 Thou+" "Rs 20,000 ~ 20 Thou+" ...
##  $ liabilities  : chr  "Rs 58,46,335 ~ 58 Lacs+" "Rs 0 ~" "Rs 0 ~" "Rs 0 ~" ...
```